# how to show a messege box for restart computer after installation in c#?

Tags: installation, c#-2.0

I want to know about how to display a message box to display a message “Please restart your computer"  with yes and no option is user click on yes then system restart. This message box want to show after complition of installation.
if is there any idea about that then please help
and I also want to know if is there any code for that then where i place this code in installer class of elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Setup Project in Visual Studio, and then have a look at this:

[HOW TO: Control System Restarts in a Setup Project That You Created by Using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=827020)